# Mongodb driver installation in php (xampp)

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am using xampp version 3.2.1 and I would like to use mongodb with php.
My version of php is 5.5.19, 32-bit win os, Compiler is MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012) in my xampp. 
I have tried using mongodb driver "php_mongo-1.6.0RC2-5.5-vc11.dll" which is a thread safe version.
When i include the extension in my php.ini file and run the phpinfo() after refreshing the apache server, mongodb is not shown in the phpinfo list. 
So what could be my problem or what version of mongo driver can I use?? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: see if extension=php_mongo-1.6.0RC2-5.5-vc11.dll of your version is available in your php.ini amke sure it is not commented.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and yeah i have made it sure. But it is not working still.

Comment: Ya i got the same error. @SuravandhithaJayaPrakash

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error... I'was trying to run php 5.6.3 with xampp using php_mongo driver version 1.6.2. I figured out that the apache server not found the lib "libsasl.dll". Copy the lib to apache bin folder, select the right version of the driver and it will work.